# How to did preg_match_all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is  Not working in Rails ??
`statement= '<p>As he opened the door, Winston saw that he had left the diary open on the table. DOWN WITH BIG BROTHER was written in it, in letters you could almost <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">read</span> across the room.</p>\r\n<p>But everything was all right. A small, sad-looking woman was standing outside.</p>\r\n<p>'Oh, Comrade Smith,' she said, in a dull little voice, 'do you think you could come across and help me with our kitchen sink? The water isn't running away and ...'</p>\r\n<p>`

```
result = statement.scan('/<span style="text-decoration: underline;">(.*)<\/span>/U')
```

Comment: the `statement` you have given is not a valid string

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this helps.
If

```
statement= "<p>As he opened the door, Winston saw that he had left the diary open on the table. DOWN WITH BIG BROTHER was written in it, in letters you could almost <span style='text-decoration: underline;'>read</span> across the room.</p>\r\n<p>But everything was all right. A small, sad-looking woman was standing outside.</p>\r\n<p>'Oh, Comrade Smith,' she said, in a dull little voice, 'do you think you could come across and help me with our kitchen sink? The water isn't running away and ...'</p>\r\n<p>".html_safe
```

then

```
result = statement.scan(/<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>.*<\/span>/)
#=> ["<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>read</span>"]
```